# Комментарии DLE, у гостей улетели формы (имаил, имя, капча)

Tags: php, cms, комментарии, form, dle

В поле добавления регистрации  у гостей улетели формы имаил, имя, капча.
[Тестовая страничка](http://andro1d.16mb.com/29-test.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте еще одну ячейку в строку с редактором, либо сделайте так:

```
 <td class="editorcomm" colspan="2">
```